# How to convert a DataFrame back to normal RDD in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to use the

```
(rdd.)partitionBy(npartitions, custom_partitioner)
```

method that is not available on the DataFrame.  All of the DataFrame methods refer only to DataFrame results.  So then how to create an RDD from the DataFrame data?

Note: this is a change (in 1.3.0) from 1.2.0.

**Update** from the answer from @dpangmao: the method is .rdd. I was interested to understand if (a) it were public and (b) what are the performance implications.

Well (a) is yes and (b) - well you can see here that there are significant perf implications: a new RDD must be created  by invoking **mapPartitions** :

In **dataframe.py** (note the file name changed as well (was sql.py):

```
@property
def rdd(self):
    """
    Return the content of the :class:`DataFrame` as an :class:`RDD`
    of :class:`Row` s.
    """
    if not hasattr(self, '_lazy_rdd'):
        jrdd = self._jdf.javaToPython()
        rdd = RDD(jrdd, self.sql_ctx._sc, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer()))
        schema = self.schema

        def applySchema(it):
            cls = _create_cls(schema)
            return itertools.imap(cls, it)

        self._lazy_rdd = rdd.mapPartitions(applySchema)

    return self._lazy_rdd
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

@dapangmao's answer works, but it doesn't give the regular spark RDD, it returns a Row object. If you want to have the regular RDD format.

Try this:

```
rdd = df.rdd.map(tuple)
```

or

```
rdd = df.rdd.map(list)
```

Comment: This should be the default behaviour imo when calling `df.rdd`

Comment: This is probably a more precise answer actually

Comment: What is the `df`, how to initialize it?

Comment: @DavidWei some Dataframe instance, so whatever variable your dataframe is assigned to

Comment: What are tuple and list ?

Comment: `Row` is a subclass of tuple, so in many most cases doing this is superfluous.

Answer (score 106):

Use the method `.rdd` like this:

```
rdd = df.rdd
```

Comment: yes you are correct. I updated the OP after digging deeper into this.

Comment: yes but it convert to org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] but not org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[string]

Comment: Technically, it's a property: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.rdd

Answer (score 7):

Answer given by kennyut/Kistian works very well but to get exact RDD like output when **RDD consist of list of attributes** e.g. [1,2,3,4] we can use flatmap command as below,

```
rdd = df.rdd.flatMap(list)
```

or

```
rdd = df.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: list(x))
```

Comment: This looks like a helpful contribution.