# is there a way convert a spark dataframe generated from a sql statement into an rdd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

if i use this spark sql statement:

```
df = spark.sql('SELECT col_name FROM table_name')
```

it will return a spark dataframe object. How can i convert this to an rdd? is there a way to read a table directly using sql but generating an rdd instead of a dataframe?

Thanks in advance

Comment: df.rdd should give you the RDD

Comment: i tried that but no, instead, i get the following error: `PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o60.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    `

Comment: i have visited a good bunch of posts here talking about more or less the same thing, but i get this error instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000514/how-to-convert-a-dataframe-back-to-normal-rdd-in-pyspark Try one of the alternatives suggested here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark - Why i can't convert a sql dataframe to an rdd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250152/pyspark-why-i-cant-convert-a-sql-dataframe-to-an-rdd)

Comment: @sramalingam24 thank you but none of those will work, i tried that already, basically, i get the error when calling `df.rdd` i just wanted to know if there's any other way of achieving the same result, or some kind of workaround for this situation

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Can you do df.show?

Comment: the data is coming froma database i have in the cloud, if i do df.show()  it works well, i see my data printed as expected, returning a one column df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = spark.sql('SELECT col_name FROM table_name')
```

`df.rdd` # you can save it, perform transformations etc.

`df.rdd` returns the content as an `pyspark.RDD` of Row.

You can then map on that `RDD` of Row transforming every Row into a `numpy` vector. I can't be more specific about the transformation since I don't know what your vector represents with the information given.

**Note 1**: `df` is the variable define our Dataframe.

**Note 2**: this function is available since Spark 1.3

Comment: Did this solve the `PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o60.__getstate__. Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)` error?